# MS CRM Webservice Error : The partner DNS used in the login request cannot be found

Tags: web-services, dns, crm, microsoft-dynamics

When I am making the call for Microsoft dynamics 2011 Integration, I am getting Error given below. Please check and correct the following :

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
             xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"
             xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <s:Header>
                <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">
                http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/RST/Issue</a:Action>
                <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:8bd921a8-1aa7-4346-a656-97580efa9a51</a:MessageID>
                <a:ReplyTo>
                  <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
                </a:ReplyTo>
                <VsDebuggerCausalityData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/diagnostics/servicemodelsink">
                uIDPozBEz+P/wJdOhoN2XNauvYcAAAAAK0Y6fOjvMEqbgs9ivCmFPaZlxcAnCJ1GiX+Rpi09nSYACQAA</VsDebuggerCausalityData>
                <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">
                https://login.live.com/liveidSTS.srf</a:To>
                <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1"
                xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
                  <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
                   <u:Created>2013-12-13T07:08:26.00</u:Created>
                   <u:Expires>2013-12-14T07:08:26.00</u:Expires>
                  </u:Timestamp>
                  <o:UsernameToken u:Id="user">
                    <o:Username>sudhir@live2support.onmicrosoft.com</o:Username>
                    <o:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">xxxxxx</o:Password>
                  </o:UsernameToken>
                  <wsse:BinarySecurityToken ValueType="urn:liveid:device"
                  xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
                    <EncryptedData Id="BinaryDAToken0"
                    Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element"
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
                      <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc">
                      </EncryptionMethod>
                      <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                        <ds:KeyName>http://Passport.NET/STS</ds:KeyName>
                      </ds:KeyInfo>
                      <CipherData>
                      <CipherValue>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"</CipherValue>
                      </CipherData>
                    </EncryptedData>
                  </wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
                </o:Security>
             </s:Header>
              <s:Body>
                <t:RequestSecurityToken xmlns:t="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust">
                  <wsp:AppliesTo xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy">
                    <a:EndpointReference>
                      <a:Address>urn:crm5.dynamics.com</a:Address>
                    </a:EndpointReference>
                  </wsp:AppliesTo>
                 <wsp:PolicyReference URI="MBI_FED_SSL"
                  xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" />
                  <t:RequestType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/Issue</t:RequestType>
                </t:RequestSecurityToken>
              </s:Body>
             </s:Envelope>
```

and RESPONSE ERROR:

The partner DNS used in the login request cannot be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FOUND :)

these “urn” are no more used in the new authentication model for CRM Online. Here is the new values you have to use:

```
Old value   New value
crm:dynamics.com    crmna:dynamics.com
crm4:dynamics.com   crmemea:dynamics.com
crm5:dynamics.com   crmapac:dynamics.com
```

Reference:

http://mscrmtools.blogspot.pt/2012/08/php-to-crm-online-easy-way-to-do.html